# Python: get the index in a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I do have a while loop without an iterable:

```
n = 0 
while x0 > xmin:
    xy.createSomeCube(x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1)
    xy.someCube(n).setSomeParameters(dx,dy,dz)

    ...

    x0 -= someDecrement(someArgument)

    ...

    n += 1
```

Is there an elegant way to omit the `n = 0` and the `n += 1` and to get the index of the current step in the while loop?

Comment: A `for` loop might not work in this case since the loop condition is based off of `x0`, not off the variable that is being incremented. `x0` is changed by some unknown quantity, so the number of iterations appears to be unknown beforehand - which is why a `while` loop is better.

Comment: `x0` and `xmin` are both variable and i want the code as flexible as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an semi-infinite range with `itertools.count`:

```
for n in itertools.count(0):
    if x0 <= xmin:
        break
    xy.createSomeCube(x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1)
    xy.someCube(n).setSomeParameters(dx,dy,dz)

    ...

    x0 -= someDecrement(someArgument)
```

You could also use

```
from itertools import count, takewhile
for n in takewhile(lambda _: x0 < xmin, count(0)):
    xy.createSomeCube(x0,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1)
    xy.someCube(n).setSomeParameters(dx,dy,dz)

    ...

    x0 -= someDecrement(someArgument)
```

but that's probably for functional-programming junkies only :)

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE:** Since you edited the post, the answer below isn't relevant anymore. I think the easiest solution is to just stick with the while loop; it's only two added lines of code (and short ones at that).  If you give more information about function/value that `x0` is decrementing by, perhaps we can find a clever solution with lists/generators so that a for loop can be used.

**PREVIOUS:**

Convert it to a for loop:

```
for n,i in enumerate(range(x0, xmin, -abc)):
    xy.createSomeCube(i,y0,z0,x1,y1,z1)
    xy.someCube(n).setSomeParameters(dx,dy,dz)
```

`i` contains your previous x0 and every iteration it decreases by abc.

`enumerate` zips an index with your items in the generated list, so n has the current index at each iteration.

EDIT: As Roger Fan pointed out, this will only work if `x0`, `xmin`, and `abc` are integers.  Otherwise you'll have to stick with the while loop.

Comment: That only works if `x0`, `xmin`, and `abc` are integers. You could use `numpy.arange` to handle floats, but it's probably not worth it over the while loop unless you're using `numpy` already.

Comment: Good call, added note at the end

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I forgot to mention that my decrement on x0 is not constant

Comment: If that's the case then you'll have to just deal with the decrement as it's own statement and stick with the while loop.  Python's for loops are not like in Java/C where you can put an arbitrary condition to break on.